# Telegram bot php. Inline keyboard. Подскажите, что делать дальше с callback_data. Что бы после нажатия на кнопку inline keyboard - бот ее обработал

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

Подскажите, пожалуйста как написать простой сценарий для бота, например:
написал команду "/test",
 бот спрашивает: "Вы уверены?"
пишешь в ответ: "Да"
бот отправляет следующее сообщение по сценарию, если пишешь "нет" - сценарий заканчивается.
Важно, что бы мой ответ "Да" не обрабатывался ботом, пока он не спросит "Вы уверены?"(после команды /test)

```
<?php

$access_token = '...';
$api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $access_token;


$output = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$chat_id = $output['message']['chat']['id'];
$first_name = $output['message']['chat']['first_name'];
$message = $output['message']['text'];
switch($message) {
 case '/test':
    sendMessage($chat_id, "Вы уверены?");
    break;
    default:
    $sorry_text =  $first_name . ' , мне нечего ответить';
    sendMessage($chat_id, $sorry_text);
}
function sendMessage($chat_id, $message, $encodedMarkup) {
  file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=' . urlencode($message) . $encodedMarkup);
}
```

Понял, что это делается через ForceReply, но как пока не разобрался.
UPDATE
сделал inline keybord, но пока не понял как выводить сообщение в зависимости от нажатой кнопки
case '/test':

```
    $x1 = array("text"=>"First Button","callback_data"=>"test1");
$x2 = array("text"=>"Second Button","callback_data"=>"test2");
$opz = [[$x1,$x2]];
$keyboard=array("inline_keyboard"=>$opz);
$keyboard = json_encode($keyboard);  
      sendMessage($chat_id, "testt2", $keyboard);
      break;
```

т.е. сейчас при нажатии на кнопку ничего не вывыодится

Comment: Как получаете обновления, через вебхуки?

Comment: Да, через вэбхуки

Comment: Можно решить через [InlineKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup), без `ForceReply`.

Comment: думал об этом, но пока только разобрался с обычной клавиатурой

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вот рабочий код, если кому нужен.

```
<?php
$access_token = 'xxx';
$api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $access_token;
$output = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$chat_id = $output['message']['chat']['id'];
$message = $output['message']['text'];
$callback_query = $output['callback_query'];
$data = $callback_query['data'];
$message_id = ['callback_query']['message']['message_id'];
$chat_id_in = $callback_query['message']['chat']['id'];
switch($message) {
    case '/test':  
    $inline_button1 = array("text"=>"Google url","url"=>"http://google.com");
    $inline_button2 = array("text"=>"work plz","callback_data"=>'/plz');
    $inline_keyboard = [[$inline_button1,$inline_button2]];
    $keyboard=array("inline_keyboard"=>$inline_keyboard);
    $replyMarkup = json_encode($keyboard); 
     sendMessage($chat_id, "ok", $replyMarkup);
    break;
}
switch($data){
    case '/plz':
    sendMessage($chat_id_in, "plz", $replyMarkup = '');
    break;
}
function sendMessage($chat_id, $message, $replyMarkup) {
  file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=' . urlencode($message) . '&reply_markup=' . $replyMarkup);
}
```

Comment: респект большое спасибо, таких как ты да побольше бы в нете, не то что умняги, что напускают на себя важности и малюют заумный код, где сам чёрт ногу сломит.

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, что должно происходить при нажатии на plz? куда должно уходить сообщение sendMessage($chat_id_in, "plz"); - почему тут $chat_id_in, а не $chat_id?

Comment: При нажатии на plz, в чате напишет 'plz'. Это будет эквивалентно команде '/plz'. Используется $chat_id_in потому что команда '/plz' должна выполнится после получения ответы от команды '/test' ($chat_id). Этим самым выстраивается цепочка команд. Если сразу ввести '/plz', то ничего не произойдет(произойдет только после команды '/test'. Как-то так.

Comment: В коде выше максимум работает это URL кнопка а при нажатии на work plz долго думает и.. ничего не происходит причем я заметил такой косяк на всех мануалах.
кто нибудь может подправить код?

Comment: Куда помещается ссылка на данный скрипт чтобы телеграм начал использовать его?